Shadcn select creating unnecessary white space at bottom of page
Depending on where I put a select component or any component that uses a popper, it creates an unnecessary white space at the bottom of the page. The select is within a div that has a custom overflow y set and I want the select pop up to be scrollable with that div component It's hard to describe with words so I will post a picture as well.
before pop down after pop down
How do I make the pop down go down with the div with the custom scrollbar and instead of just the page in general?
I tried changing the styling of the Select component itself as well as the max height and although that does work, I don't like how the pop up looks because its so small.
Here is the select component I am using, there are multiple of them within the form that all function relatively the same way:
     <FormField
        control={form.control}
        name="startTimeHour"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <FormItem>
            <FormLabel>Start Hour</FormLabel>
            <Select onValueChange={field.onChange}>
              <FormControl>
                <SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectValue
                    placeholder={event ? dateObj.startHour : "01"}
                  />
                </SelectTrigger>
              </FormControl>
              <SelectContent className="bg-white overflow-y-auto">
                {hourArray.map((hour) => {
                  return (
                    <SelectItem key={hour} value={hour}>
                      {hour}
                    </SelectItem>
                  );
                })}
              </SelectContent>
            </Select>
            <FormMessage />
          </FormItem>
        )}
      />

Here is the styling of the div it is affecting:
.common-container {
@apply flex flex-col flex-1 items-center gap-10 overflow-y-scroll py-10 px-5 md:px-8 lg:p-14 custom-scrollbar;

}
This issue only occurs when the page is full of elements, so you probably won't notice anything if you test with just one of these selects. I have a bottom bar that sticks to the bottom of the page and when you scroll all the way down there is just extra whitespace below the bottom bar, I need to either adjust the bottom bar to stick below that white space or for the div's content to expand when the select component drops down.

You need to try by yourself and then show us, where you got problems and then we will help you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have tried by myself why do you think I’m asking here @1stthomas

I’ve tried changing the styling of the overflow, max height, z index, height of parent div, I’ve tried changing how the pop up drops down so it drops up instead but that didn’t work either. I’ve tried rearranging elements on the page , but nothing has been able to solve my problem. I need it so that the content of the parent div expands when the pop up drops down, instead of the parent having extra flex space that it doesn’t expand to at the bottom.

But we can't help you without some code, meaning a reproducable example of code.

Wrap your form in a div with className="relative". Radix has absolutely positioned elements that when used with overflow will cause layout issues.
For me I had to change sr-only to fixed sr-only.
I also had the same issue with Radix's Select as this has absolutely positioned elements inside a portal. To fix that I use.
/*
 ** Used to ensure proper layout and positioning of child components,
 ** when using select which makes use of absolute positioning inside a portal.
 **
 ** By setting this div to 'position: relative', we establish a containing block for any absolutely
 ** positioned descendants. This prevents them from escaping the bounds of the form and affecting
 ** the page's overall layout, which could cause issues like unexpected scrolling or extra space.
 */
const SelectWrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
  <div className="relative inline-block w-full">{children}</div>
);

A <SelectWrapper> around my select component. I originally had className="relative" on a div wrapping the children of the form. This broke the layout / spacing of my labels / inputs so I relocated it to a select wrapper.
